# Totals of a record in an associated table (sum ())

Tags: cakephp, associations, inner-join, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

In Cakephp 3.8 calculate the sum of a column from an associated table. As in this SQL:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.number, SUM(items.total_uncovered) FROM orders
INNER JOIN items ON orders.id = items.order_id
GROUP BY orders.id
```

I'm trying like this:

```
$orders = $this->Orders->find();
$orders->contain(['Items']);
$orders->select([
             'id',
             'number',
             'order_total_uncovered' => $orders
                 ->newExpr()
                 ->add($orders->func()
                 ->sum(new identifierExpression('Items.total_uncovered')))
         ]);
$orders->limit(20);
```

and I get the message:

```
"Unknown column 'Items.total_uncovered' in 'field list'"
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to utilize `SUM()`, and I don't see any join tables, I'd assume that the `Items` association is `hasMany`.

By default `hasMany` (and `belongsToMany`) associated data is being retrieved in a separate query when contained, hence the field won't show up in your main query. You'll have to explicitly join in the association instead, which can be done using the `innerJoinWith()` and `leftJoinWith()` methods.

Also note that you don't need to wrap the function into another expression, and you can use a callback for `select()` to obtain a reference to the query, and last but not least, there's also an `identifier()` shorthand method for creating identifier expressions:

```php
$orders = $this->Orders
    ->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            'Orders.id',
            'Orders.number',
            'order_total_uncovered' => $query->func()->sum(
                $query->identifier('Items.total_uncovered')
            )
        ];
    })
    ->innerJoinWith('Items')
    ->group('Orders.id')
    ->limit(20);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations > Using innerJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using Identifiers in Expressions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-identifiers-in-expressions)**